# Run command from C#

Tags: c#

Folks,
I have a simple expression that I am able to run by pasting it in the "search program and files" :

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\notepad.exe" /BF: "D:\BatchMerge\DcaBatch.bpf"*

If I have use the same expression in the C# code, what should I use? I searched on stackflow and found `"Process.startinfo"`. I tried using it as below:

```
Process.Start(""C:\Program Files (x86)\notepad.exe" /BF: "D:\BatchMerge\DcaBatch.bpf"");
```

That does not work!

Comment: escape your double quote and it will work

Comment: I did. It says "unrecognizable escape sequence" wherever I have "\" in the expression.

Comment: because you also need to escape your \ in c:\

Comment: How to escape strings properly is a very basic task that all developers need to know. You need to go learn how this works in .NET strings.

Comment: @Will : I am new to C#. Agree on the learning part but I don't buy the concept of giving "-" . Not everyone on the forum knows everything. Anyway thnx.

Comment: SO isn't a forum, and it's not the right place to learn how to program. You'd do yourself a good service to buy a good C# book like CLR Via C# and read it. Shouldn't take more than a day and you can avoid getting dinged for asking very basic questions. You can learn more about how SO works by visiting [meta]. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the executable from the arguments. Look at [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx). So you'd do this instead:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\notepad.exe", "/BF: \"D:\\BatchMerge\\DcaBatch.bpf\"");
```